# Scoping (functions) in custom environment

Tags: r, function, scope, sandbox

I have a special (dummy) function which I want to use in a sandboxed environment:

```
disable.system.call <- function(...) {
    mc <- match.call()
    if (grepl('system', deparse(mc[[2]])))
        stop('NONO')
    eval(mc, env = .GlobalEnv)        
}
```

It does nothing special just checks if the first argument has the `system` word in its name. This is just a POC example.

What I do later: I assign this simple functions to some `base` and `stats` functions to see if evaluated expressions do contain the `system` word as the first argument. E.g.:

```
e <- new.env()
eval(parse(text = 'model.frame <- disable.system.call'), envir = e)
```

This works pretty cool, as calls without `system` inside works like a charm, but the filter works:

```
> eval(parse(text = 'model.frame("1 ~ 1")'), envir = e)
  1
1 1
> eval(parse(text = 'model.frame(\'1 ~ system("ls -la")\')'), envir = e)
Error in model.frame("1 ~ system(\"ls -la\")") : NONO
```

It's even working with an `lm` call which calls `model.frame` inside of found a formula like string:

```
> eval(parse(text = 'lm(\'1 ~ system("ls -la")\')'), envir = e)
Error in model.frame(formula = "1 ~ system(\"ls -la\")", drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  NONO
```

I tried to go a bit further and assigned that pretty simple function (`disable.system.call`) to `as.formula` which is called from `model.frame`. Unfortunately I did not got so far:

```
> e <- new.env()
> eval(parse(text = 'as.formula <- disable.system.call'), envir = e)
> eval(parse(text = 'as.formula("1 ~ 1")'), envir = e)
1 ~ 1
> eval(parse(text = 'as.formula(\'1 ~ system("ls -la")\')'), envir = e)
Error in as.formula("1 ~ system(\"ls -la\")") : NONO
> eval(parse(text = 'model.frame(\'1 ~ system("ls -la")\')'), envir = e)
  1 system("ls -la")
1 1                0
> eval(parse(text = 'lm(\'1 ~ system("ls -la")\')'), envir = e)

Call:
lm(formula = "1 ~ system(\"ls -la\")")

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)  system("ls -la")  
           1                NA
```

As I know `model.frame` is calling `as.formula` but this does not work (as you can see from the above output). I am quite sure it's not because `model.frame` is calling `stats::as.formula` as `lm` called above `model.frame` in the custom environment.

Any hints and ideas would be really welcomed!

Answer (score 4):

Although you suspected it wasn't the case, `stats:::model.frame.default` is being called, instead of the custom version in environment `e`. (This is of course the behavior you'd generally expect from packaged functions. The odd scoping seen in your first example is a special case, due to `lm()`'s use of 'non-standard evaluation', which is discussed at the bottom of my answer).

As I show below, you can use `trace()` to see which version of `as.formula()` is getting called in each of your cases:

```
disable.system.call <- function(...) {
    mc <- match.call()
    if (grepl('system', deparse(mc[[2]])))
        stop('NONO')
    eval(mc, env = .GlobalEnv)        
}
e <- new.env()
eval(parse(text = 'as.formula <- disable.system.call'), envir = e)


# (1) trace custom 'as.formula()' in environment e
trace(e$as.formula)


# Calling model.frame() **does not** call the the custom as.formula()
eval(parse(text = 'model.frame(\'1 ~ system("ls -la")\')'), envir = e)
#   1 system("ls -la")
# 1 1              127

# (2) trace stats:::as.formula()
trace(stats:::as.formula)

# Calling model.frame() **does** call stats:::as.formula()
eval(parse(text = 'model.frame(\'1 ~ system("ls -la")\')'), envir = e)
# trace: as.formula
#   1 system("ls -la")
# 1 1              127
```

---

**Edit**: FWIW, the reason that your custom `model.frame()` **was** called by `lm()` in the first example is that `lm()` employs what is sometimes called 'non-standard evaluation'. ([See this pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=standard%20non-standard%20evaluation%20rules&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) for more on the subject than you're likely to ever want.) The key bit is that `lm()` actually directs `model.frame()` to be evaluated in the calling environment; in your case, this led to it's finding your version of the function.

The reason that `lm()` uses non-standard evaluation is so that `model.frame()` can access variables named in the formula even if they are found in the calling environment (rather than just being able to access variables passed in via the `data` argument to `lm()`). As Thomas Lumley says in the linked pdf:

> If variables in the formula were required to be in the data argument life would be a lot simpler, but this requirement was not made when formulas were introduced.

In case you're interested, here are the relevant lines from the definition of `lm`:

```
mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
...
mf[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")
mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really useful (+1) - despite the fact that I've looked through the relevant R sources (and of course I realized that `model.frame.default` is called as there is no other methods - if I am right), I just somehow passed the `eval` call in `lm`'s sources. This makes things clear of course! I just need to find a simple way to force functions to use my special `as.formula` (like @RichieCotton's anwer), or to grep R sources for all occurrence of `as.formula` etc. or so. Ah, and thanks for that _pdf_ too!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want people to be able to use `system`, it would be easier to overwrite the definition.

```
assignInNamespace(
  "system", 
  function(...) stop("system calls are not allowed"), 
  getNamespace("base")
)

system("pwd")  #throws an error
```

---

I'm wildly guessing at your use case, but are you letting users pass arbitrary R code to some other application?  In which case you probably want to compile your own version of R, with the dangerous functions removed or replaced by dummies.

---

One other possibility for executing custom code when a function is called is `trace`.  For example,

```
trace(system, quote(stop("You have called system")))  #you may also want print = FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is handy too (+1)! As a matter of fact I do not want to forbid all `system` calls, it was just a simple POC example, but I want to implement a sandbox environment indeed. Pls see: http://sandboxr.no-ip.org/ Anyway, `assignInNamespace` seems promising, I need some time to do some experiments after Easter and will definitely give more detailed feedback.

Comment: Nice project.  Have you seen Live-R, which does a similar thing? http://live-analytics.com

Comment: Never heard of Live-R, thanks for pointing my attention to that neat piece of software! I am up to something similar indeed, but with special (expected) audience. We will see :) Anyway, about your answer: as `?assignInNamespace` suggest to not use this feature in a package (like I'd like to) and does not allow me to enable/disable sandbox environment, it seems that I have to find another way to deactivate these calls. Like `grep`ing R sources for similar functions :) What I want to do is to run calls in a special environment, outside of that anything is allowed (for system-side calls).